# Is there a document which lists compatible SQL versions against SQLPackage.exe?

Tags: sql-server

We are using SQLPackage.exe v13.*, which doesn't seem to work with SQL Server 2019 (unsurprisingly).

We can move to SQLPackage.exe v19 (latest), but I want to ensure backwards compatibility.

Is there an article which says SQLPackage.exe vX is supported by SQL Server vY?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLPackage v13 is pretty old. I'm not sure when it came out, but well before SQL Server 2019 was released. Therefore SQLPackage v13 will have no idea how to interact with SQL Server 2019--it can't be guaranteed to be compatible with the future.

In general, SQL Server tools will support the versions of SQL Server that were supported at the time it was released. So the current SQLPackage v19 can be expected to work on all supported SQL Server versions (2012+).

I *think* that Microsoft changed the versioning scheme for SQLPackage after 2016. (I can't seem to find the docs to confirm though, and don't have a copy handy.) Up until SQL Server 2016, `sqlpackage.exe` and SQL Server shared the version numbers, so v13 is both SQL Server 2016 & SQLPackage from 2016. After that, the SQLPackage version number diverges and does it's own thing.

If you are using the latest version of SQL Server (currently 2019), you'll need to also use the latest version of SQLPackage (currently 19.0). The latest version will also work with all currently-supported SQL Server versions, so unless you're using an ancient version of the database engine, the latest version of SQLPackage will work globally for all your database servers.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you.